# Remove exceptions from log file

Tags: bash

Remove exceptions from log file

```
 cat ignore_err.txt|grep -v "^#"| while read line;
  do
  cp atln_output_err.txt atln_output_err.txt.bak4 ;
  echo "start  ....... $line  ";
  sed '/$file/d' atln_output_err.txt >out.txt
  mv out.txt atln_output_err.txt
  echo "end   .......  $line   ";
  done
start  ....... \} INFO  aop\:
end   .......  \} INFO  aop\:
start  ....... Not able to find an user based on email address
end   .......  Not able to find an user based on email address
```

I need to remove these lines from input file in each iteration of loop

Above script does not filter records from input file in each iteration of loop.

Is there any other efficient way to do it

Thanks

---

I have this exception list
  **cat ignore_err.txt**

```
#aop:83 - Entering AccessController.msb3IeError
#aop:83 - Leaving AccessController.msb3IeError
#\\} DEBUG  aop\\:
\\} INFO  aop\\:
Not able to find an user based on email address
```

I want to filter the log file (atln_output_err.txt) having these keywords contains

I want to achieve this

```
 cat atln_output_err.txt   | grep -v  "\} INFO  aop\:"   | grep -v  "Not able to find an user based on email address"   >a.txt
```

---

Comment: You will need to clarify your question as it is a mess. What exactly you need to remove? Separate the code from the expected output. Also you have a useless `cat`, you should grep the file itself `grep -v "^#" ignore_err.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -v "^#" ignore_err.txt| while read i;
do
grep -v "$i" log_err.txt >out.txt
mv out.txt log_err.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put all error keywords in a file called `error_keyword.txt` (linefeed separated)

_ To get all log entries without those matching error keywords :

```
grep -v -F -f error_keyword.txt log.txt
```

_ To get all log entries that match error keywords :

```
grep -i -F -f error_keyword.txt log.txt
```

---

- -v will give you entries that dont match input file (-f)
- -i will give you entries that match input file (-f)
- -F will interpret input pattern as plain text (to avoid interpretation of special characters)

Then you can redirect to a file :

```
grep -v -F -f error_keyword.txt log.txt > log_without_errors.txt
```